# GoJs Diagram after expanding is changing the scroll position

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have an expand button clicking on which expands the diagram to full scale. But after scrolling, the scroll bar automatically scrolls down to the middle of the diagram. I want the very first node to be visible on screen after I expand the diagram.

On page load the image looks something like this-
[image]

After I click on the Full View button at the top right corner, the image looks like this-
[image]

The scroll automatically gets shifted to the center of the diagram. I need to show the top most node of the diagram on Full View button click.

Comment: Could you please explain precisely what you mean when your button "expands the diagram to full scale", what you mean by "after scrolling", and what you mean by "the very first node"?

Comment: Hi @WalterNorthwoods, Thanks for the reply. Have updated the query. Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **Diagram.scale** the way that you want and then call **CommandHandler.scrollToPart**.

```
  var node = ...;  // what you want to be sure to show
  myDiagram.commandHandler.scrollToPart(node);
```

Examples are at:
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowgrammer.html
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartStatic.html (but is commented out)

A fancier example is at:
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/animatedFocus.html